# Pooling storage across multiple devices?

Tags: networking, samba, storage

Is it possible to pool storage across multiple (eg.) Raspberry Pi's into one store? For a simple example, say I have 12 Pi's, each Pi has 1TB of on a USB. Can I make a single storage on the network (using samba or something), that would appear as a single 12TB drive, and automatically distribute the data across the various drives as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you might take a look at GlusterFS.

Here's a write-up (not mine) I used for reference on my own project, [Deploying Glusterfs on Odroid HC2s](https://blog.jburt.me/2019/07/deploying-glusterfs-on-odroid-hc2s.html).

Comment: Thanks for this resource as well. I think the use case is kind of similar. Basically my thinking is that a single board computer is capped by the number of USB drives that can be attached. So I'm wondering if I can increase the capacity by combining the storage of multiple computers. 

Kind of like a RAID of crappy computers.

Comment: That's basically why I use this scheme. The caveat is that by default you've got no data redundancy. You could get fancy, put two USB disks on each Pi4 and mirror them with mdadm, then run gluster on top of that, or just have a good backup scheme if you're unconcerned. Check out the options for storage architecture (gluster has excellent docs): https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Architecture/

Answer (score 2):

Look into [iSCSI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ISCSI/LIO) which allows you to build RAID arrays over different fabrics, including IP/Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As well as glusterfs, which has already been mentioned, there's [Ceph](http://ceph.com/) which provides RAID-like redundancy, and allows you to access the distributed storage pool in multiple ways:

- as a [POSIX-compliant file system](https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/cephfs/),
- as [network block devices](https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/rbd/) (e.g. for net-booted physical and virtual client machines),
- and as an [object store](https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/radosgw/) with APIs compatible with both [Amazon's S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.htm) and [Openstack's Swift](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Swift).

---

However, it's worth noting that when you add up the cost of multiple rpi machines (a dozen raspberry pis will cost at least $420 USD, not including USB power supplies or 3D-printed cases), you'll find it's cheaper (and easier and more reliable) to just buy a second-hand PC with multiple SATA ports (many motherboards have 6 or 8 SATA ports built-in, plus several PCI-e slots for expansion), with a case and power supply and cooling fans (and usually places to mount additional fans).  In fact, it's not difficult to scavenge such machines for free when businesses (or schools or individuals) upgrade to newer hardware.

If you need more than 6 or 8 drives, optionally add a multi-port SAS card (like an LSI eight or sixteen SAS/SATA port, e.g. an 8-port IBM-branded M1015 LSI card costs around $100 USD on ebay).

If all you want is a DIY NAS or file-server, then use ZFS (or mdadm RAID) to combine the drives into one or more pools/arrays and share them on the network with NFS and/or Samba.

Comment: FYI, see https://www.youtube.com/c/JeffGeerling/videos  for some cool stuff being done with rpis.

Comment: >However, it's worth noting that when you add up the cost of multiple rpi machines to just buy a second-hand PC with multiple SATA ports  

I agree, the question isn't about should it be done, but can it be done.

>FYI, see youtube.com/c/JeffGeerling/videos for some cool stuff being done with rpis  
^_^

Comment: @BenjaminCollins oh yeah, i absolutely understand that it's fun and educational to to tinker and to play with technology to find out what it's capable of, what you can make it do.  but tinkering isn't necessarily compatible with reliably storing data that you want to be able to get back and use, nor is it always cheaper than doing things in a more "mainstream" way. Personally, I do both and keep my tinkering separate from the things I need to be reliable :-)